# Replaying HTTP requests on multiple servers and comparing the results

Tags: java, http, testing, proxy, functional-testing

I have two different implementations of an application, which should return identical results for identical requests. The second implementation is a re-write of the application, so we can consider the first implementation as the reference.

I have the idea of testing the second implementation by comparing the results returned from it to the results returned by the first one for identical requests.

Ideally, I'd want to do this on a large number of HTTP requests, recorded from an operational deployment (using some proxy to record, or access log).

I'm looking for a set of tools that makes this scenario possible without too much coding (alternative is that I can write a tool to do this for me) :

1. Record requests on production (Access logs, Charles proxy, etc.)
2. Replay the requests on both servers
3. Detect any difference in returned response

I've seen similar approaches for real-world load testing (using JMeter to replay access logs, or what Charles Proxy does) but what I need in addition is the comparison of results to have *functional* testing.

The target system is on a Java implementation family (Servlet containers, JSP, log4j, etc.) if this may have something to do with the answer, but I figure this is a pure HTTP, Network and functional testing problem and the solution may be independent from server type and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) would be a good place to start. You can have it [replay your access log](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) and it has the option to add assertions. 
EDIT:
After looking into it some more. You can add two Access Log Samplers that read the same log and fire to your two different servers. Add a post processor node to each of them that extracts the body and assigns them to a variable. Then you can use assertions to compare the two. [Read about using those elements](http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/extracting-text-from-a-page-and-using-it-somewhere-else-in-jmeter).